# Getting the squiggly even if i imported the relevant class libraries

Tags: java, collections

```
package list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class list {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       List l = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

================================================================================================

Getting squiggly for List and Array list

Comment: Modern Java doesn't like weak typing. What do you intend to *put* in the `List`? You need to tell the compiler too

Comment: Those are [*raw types*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). You should not use *raw types*. That is **probably** why you get squiggles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Eclipse. But now i am getting error while inserting or adding elements in the List. like List<?> l = new  ArrayList(); then l.add(10);?? why??

Comment: @g00se Wy should i tell the list what i'm putting in it?? Isn't that the actual advantage of the List that i can add any type of element in it??

Comment: Ignoring the "squigglies" you might find somewhere along the line you or someone else might be bitten by not knowing the type in there. That's why strong typing exists, so the compiler can check the 'future' of your collection

Comment: If you want a `List` of integers you need to tell it you want a list of integers, not a `List` of capture-of; and you're still using a raw-type on the right hand side (don't do that). `List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();`